# REGEX possible?

Tags: google-sheets

sample [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1scZ_jlw6Wx1xH3gQ_z9rBAadyw6WxqcbFk10VQIDjHk/edit#gid=234896979)

**input**: ~|AAA|BBB|~|~|~|BBB|AAA|~|~|CCC|DDD|AAA|~|AAA|~|EEE|~

**output**: @AAA|BBB@@@@BBB|AAA@@@CCC|DDD|AAA@@AAA@@EEE@

Using Google-Sheets REGEX functions - is it possible to get the output from input ?

The rules are :

1. any "|" adjacent to "~" should become a "@"
2. all "~" disappear
3. ignore the 3 letter words (which are variable length alpha numeric strings)

I have done this using 3 SUBSTITUTE statements but this bloats my already big formula the string literal arguments are error prone. So can this be done with a REGEX function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because '[lookarounds](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)' are not supported in RE2 (the regex engine used by google sheets), I'm afraid you'll need at least two functions to get the desired result.

See if this works:

```
=substitute(regexreplace(A1, "~\||\|~", "@"), "@|", "@@")
```

Comment: Thanks, that was the answer that I was looking for, the regex limit available.